# What is the difference between (*it).first and it->first?

Tags: c++11, iterator

What is the difference between `(*it).first` and `it->first`? 
Can they be used interchangeably, for example in the below code?
Also, would really help if someone has a good resource where I can learn about iterators. Specifically about this line  `vector<pair<int, int>>:: iterator it;` Can someone explain it?

```
vector<pair<int, int>> adj[10005]; //For storing vertices, weights of a directed graph as an adjacency list

for(int i = 1; i <= V; i++)//GOING THROUGH EACH VERTEX
{
  vector<pair<int, int>>:: iterator it;
  for(it = adj[i].begin(); it != adj[i].end(); it++)
  {
   cout<<it->first<<" ";
   cout<<it->second<<"\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Technically there is a difference. Practically there's no difference.

Comment: As for recommending resources, that's off topic for this site

Comment: Ok, here is a great site I just found 
 https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/iterators.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterators are designed so that they are used like pointers would. For pointers, `p->expr` is a "shorthand" for `(*p).expr`, so iterators are designed so that `it->expr` does the same thing as `(*it).expr`. If all you want is to know how to use them, then know that `it->expr` and `(*it).expr` are equivalent.

If you want to know a little more of what's under the hood then read on.

The standard just defines some restrictions and requirements for how iterators are implemented, but doesn't define the actual type. So for random access iterators (e.g. `std::vector<int>::iterator`) the iterator can be an alias for a pointer. Some implementations, especially in debug mode define an actual class for the iterator for extra safety checks. And for non-random access iterators the only option is to define an iterator class.

If it's a class then:

- `(*it)` will call `Iterator::operator*()` which should return a reference to the *pointed* object. And then `.expr` is just a member access operator for that pointed type.
- `it->expr` will call `Iterator::operator->()` which should return a pointer to the *pointed* object and then access the `expr` member.

[Operators in C and C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

[operator overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)